# clip tag does not work with corner in drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

There is code for progress bar drawable and both progress and background has the corner radis code but it seems like progress corner does not work with clip property I use clip property for vertical progress bar:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="9dip"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/bottom_bar_color"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/bottom_bar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="9dip"/>
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#fff" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: See below image the progress corner is not rounded like background of progress bar.]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found this answer while trying

```
 <scale
                android:drawable="@drawable/shape_round"
                android:scaleHeight="100%"
                android:scaleGravity="bottom"/>
```

It now round the corner for progress

shape_round.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="9dip" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```